# Is there any way i can enclose a text in latex

Tags: latex

first of all i'm new in latex

I wanted to ask if there is a way where i can enlose a text like a code like here in stack overflow thank you very much.

Ive searched here but i dont really know what to seek or how to ask something like this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not clear, please be more specific so people can help you.

Comment: Also, LaTeX-specific questions are generally better asked on tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry guys i didnt know about tex.staeckexchange.com i ll ask my question there.And yes i know  my question isnt very clear and sorry for that but i couldnt find any relative topic with that i had in my mind .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you mean by code like text. But you can use \verbatim to display some code like the following if this is what you wanted:

```
\begin{verbatim}
for i in range(1, 20):
  print i
else:
  print "the loop is done"
\end{verbatim}
```